Government Interest
Is working in government institutions that finance government projects, collect and manage loans on behalf of the government haram?
This is because some of the loans are liable to interest during repayment and also some of the projects accounts generate interest for the institution..

This is my private opinion: we do no longer live in times that silver was repaid with silver, gold with gold and wheat with wheat. Money, today, is a number printed on a piece of paper, or in the storage of your bank's computers. It is debased frequently, not in he way of the olden times, where coins of silver and gold were diluted with cheaper metals, but by inflation, giving out new money that has no counter value. For a loaf of bread, you have to pay more, and more, and more each year. I don't believe that this kind of money is haram to be lend on interests.

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider the [tour] and check our [help].
